# Comparision could not compare C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a problem about comparison from value enter by user and the database.

This is variable

```
List <string> onewayorigin = new List<string>();
List <string> onewaydestination = new List<string>();      
List <string> onewayterminal = new List<string>();
List <string> onewaydeparture = new List<string>();
```

And here is my connection to database to get the value.

```
string strSelect;
SqlCommand cmdSelect;
SqlDataReader dtr;


SqlConnection conCust;
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
conCust = new SqlConnection(connStr);

strSelect = "Select * From Route";

cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conCust);

conCust.Open();
dtr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

while (dtr.Read())
{
    onewayorigin.Add(dtr["OneWayOrigin"].ToString());
    onewaydestination.Add(dtr["OneWayDestination"].ToString());            
    onewayterminal.Add(dtr["OneWayTerminal"].ToString());   
    onewaydeparture.Add(dtr["OneWayDepartureTime"].ToString());            
}

string[] origin = onewayorigin.ToArray();
string[] destination = onewaydestination.ToArray();
string[] ow_terminal = onewayterminal.ToArray();
string[] ow_depart = onewaydeparture.ToArray();
```

And here I do my comparison.

```
if (ow_terminal.Equals(ddlterminal.SelectedValue) && ow_depart.Equals(ddlDeparture.SelectedValue))
{
    if (origin.Equals(ddlOrigin.SelectedValue) && destination.Equals(ddlDestination.SelectedValue))
    {  
        lblMessage.Text = "Record exist";
    }                
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "No record exist";
}
```

Yes, I admit I am new.

Comment: you try compare array with string??? possibly you need [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhkz42b3(v=vs.100).aspx) instead

Comment: And what *happens*? You've shown some code, told us there's a problem, but not described what the problem *is*

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are comparing array and string. This will always give you `false` as a result.

Use `Contains` instead. As shown below:

```
if (ow_terminal.Contains(ddlterminal.SelectedValue) && ow_depart.Contains(ddlDeparture.SelectedValue))
{

    if (origin.Contains(ddlOrigin.SelectedValue) && destination.Contains(ddlDestination.SelectedValue))
    {

        lblMessage.Text = "Record exist";
    }
}
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "No record exist";
}
```

Comment: yeah. Its works. But now I got another problem. If I enter same terminal, same origin and same destination but different departure, it still show me record exist. How come?, It should be no record exist. I guess the program detect the data store in array and if anyone of the record same as the record store in the array, it will show record exist?

Comment: Yes you are right. The code mentioned above will check that whether selected department exists in array or not. And If it exists then it will go inside `If Condition`

Comment: @basiclearner : Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it helped you. So that it may help other developers also.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison fail because you are comparing a complete array, with a single value:

```
ow_terminal.Equals(ddlterminal.SelectedValue)
  ^ this is an array                 ^ this is properly a string
```

To fix this you need to **loop through the arrays** to make sure, the elements (in the array) matches the value in `ddlterminal.SelectedValue`

Example:

```
foreach(string terminal in ow_terminal)
{ 
  if(terminal == ddlterminal.SelectedValue)
  { 
    ...
```

However this can be easier done with the `Contains` method:

```
if(ow_terminal.Contains(ddlterminal.SelectedValue) && ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give indexes to the items once u add in the List.
So that while comparing you should take the item index into consideration so that you compare the corresponding values.
You can user ArrayList class

```
ArrayList  onewayorigin = new ArrayList() ;
ArrayList  onewaydestination = new  ArrayList() ; 
ArrayList  onewayterminal = new ArrayList() ;
ArrayList  onewaydeparture = new ArrayList() ;
string strSelect;
SqlCommand cmdSelect;
SqlDataReader dtr;

SqlConnection conCust;
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
conCust = new SqlConnection(connStr);

strSelect = "Select * From Route";
cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(strSelect, conCust);
conCust.Open();
dtr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();

while (dtr.Read())
{
    i = 0;
    onewayorigin.Insert(i, dtr["OneWayOrigin"].ToString());
    onewaydestination.Insert(i, dtr["OneWayDestination"].ToString());            
    onewayterminal.Insert(i, dtr["OneWayTerminal"].ToString());   
    onewaydeparture.Insert(i, dtr["OneWayDepartureTime"].ToString());   
    i++         
}

//to compare
for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < arr.Count; iIndex++)
{
    object o = arr[iIndex];
    if (ow_terminal[iIndex].ToString().Contains(ddlterminal.SelectedValue) &&    ow_depart[iIndex].ToString().Contains(ddlDeparture.SelectedValue))
    {

        if (onewayorigin[iIndex].ToString().Contains(ddlOrigin.SelectedValue) && destination[iIndex].ToString().Contains(ddlDestination.SelectedValue))
        {

            lblMessage.Text = "Record exist";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "No record exist";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "No record exist";
    }
}
```

Mark as helpful if this helped..